# Computing fundamental groups of some figures

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

As an excercise of my Algebraic topology lessons, I have to compute the fundamental group of the following figures: [image]

There is no any information, only the drawing, so I am a little bit lost on how to proceed. I intuit that I have to search deformation retracts, probably on the upper circles, but I am getting confusing and I do not know what to do. Any possible help would be appreciated :)

EDIT

This is a diagram with the transformations I think can be done on the second figure in order to see it as the wedge of annulus[image]

Then, as both annuli has $\Bbb{S}^1$ as deformation retract, the fundamental group it would be $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$. Is this fine?

SECOND EDIT
If we consider two loops, move the tubes and then flatten them, it remains a cylinder with two covers each of them with the interior of a disk removed. This figure has $\Bbb{S}^1$ as deformation retract.

[image]

Comment: Look at the right picture and consider the "vertical circle" that you have drawn in the middle. The space drawn here is the result of gluing the left and right half of the picture along this circle. Can you see that these halves are both annuli and continue from there?

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks for your answer! I do not see how those halves are each of them an annuli, sorry

Comment: Move the "tube" that's sticking out a bit more towards the center and then "flatten" the resulting figure.

Comment: @thorgott Okay, know I see it. If I am not wrong, $\Bbb{S}^1$ is a deformation retract of the annulus, so the fundamental group of each half is $\Bbb{Z}$ and therefore the fundamental group of the figure would be $\Bbb{Z} \ast \Bbb{Z}$. Is this fine?

Comment: In the second figure there are two loops drawn for you and only one of them is nontrivial. In the first figure one loop is drawn for you and is non-trivial. Think about making other loops that connect to the non-trivial loop and see if you can contract them or reduce them to the existing loop.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks for the idea but, in fact this figure is the one that Thorgott was talking to me. The one that I have not solve yet is the first.

Comment: In the first figure consider loops around the two other tubular extensions besides the loop that is given. Now stretch the loops so that they all share a basepoint which is the wedge of three circles. If we do the same thing in the second figure all three loops can be moved along the surface so that they overlap with the vertical loop or can be contracted to a point like the horizontal loop. If you try to do that on the first figure what changes? What does that imply about the fundamental group?

Comment: @Daniel_Garcia You're not applying Seifert-van Kampen correctly; the intersection has to be taken into account. The result of our previous observations is that the right figure is the result of taking two annuli and gluing them together one boundary circle of each. Can you see a different way of describing that figure geometrically?

Comment: @Thorgott I was not thinking on Seifert Van Kampen, more on that the figure is wedge of the halves and since each of them has $\Bbb{S}^1$ as deformation retract the whole figure is $\Bbb{S}^1 \lor \Bbb{S}^1$. Is this wrong? I do not see the other way you say to describe the figure

Comment: @CyclotomicField Excuse me but I do not see how to "stretch" the loops you said in order to share the wedge.

Comment: @DanielGarcía get a Y-shaped stick and some yarn. Tie a loop loosely around all three branches. Now bunch all three loops together near the join of the Y.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Okay, thanks , know I understand it but I do not see what implies

Comment: @DanielGarcia The second arrow in the picture you added is inaccurate. The figure is not homotopy-equivalent to the wedge sum of both halves. The two halves intersect in a copy of $S^1$, not in a point.

Comment: @Thorgott Is the last edit I made better?

Comment: @DanielGarcía the second edit is better and you're correctly figured out that the fundamental group for the second figure is $S^1$. The deformation retract you've drawn show you how the two loops could eventually be made to circle the same tube and therefore are homotopic. The question for the first figure is can you do that or not? If not, it's the wedge of three circles. If you can, it will either be the wedge of two circles or $S^1$ again.

Comment: Yes, the second edit correct. An alternative way of describing it is a sphere with two small open disks removed, which has a deformation retract to the equatorial $S^1$: